# Intellij Idea How to show tests covering line

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm using IDEA in order to analyze our code coverage.
I can see that some lines were called N number of times. But I also want to know which test caused that line call. 
I see the appropriate button "Show tests covering line", but this button is disabled for all of the lines.

So what is the reason of that behavior and is it possible to force IDEA to show tests which called a particular line of the code

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-code-coverage-results.html#coverage-in-editor):

> For JUnit tests, you can open the test that covers a line in a separate dialog. To do so, click the the Show Tests Covering Line icon in the popup. To be able to use this feature, enable the Tracing mode and Track per test coverage options for the current run/debug configuration in the Code Coverage area. For more information, refer to [Set coverage in run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#coverage-run-configurations).

The [Set Coverage in run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#coverage-run-configurations) page details how to do this for your IDE version. Newer versions will have a Coverage Tab, older versions will not. The set up instructions for both are detailed in this page.

Comment: Would be nice to have that as a tooltip

Comment: This response is out of date. In the 2022.2 docs, there is no reference to a 'tracing mode', and no reference for how to enable the button

Comment: I just found the portion of the documentation which covers this, found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#coverage-run-configurations). Scroll down until you find tracing options for your IDE version.

Comment: Pay attention to use a **JUnit Run/Debug Configuration** where you set `Enable branch coverage and test tracking`. I ran the tests via Gradle (`gradlew clean test`) with the coverage option enabled but I couldn't get the linked test.